# Error: The type or namespace name 'DesignAutomation' does not exist in the namespace 'Autodesk.Forge'

Tags: .net-core, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to run Forge Sample to scale a model using .Net Core.
I get the Error: The type or namespace name 'DesignAutomation' does not exist in the namespace 'Autodesk.Forge' because of the `Using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation;` statement. I have added the package Autodesk.Forge 1.9.0. The same for `Using Autodesk.Forge.Core;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding packages Autodesk.Forge.Core and Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation old versions (1.0.0 and 3.0.0)

Comment: You don't need to add , Autodesk.Forge.Core explicitly, for Design Automation you need https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/